# Is using Nazi symbol in India offensive?

Tags: india, freedom-of-speech

I wanted to know whether using hitler's quote / Nazi symbol / Photo in car, social networking sites considered offensive in India ? Will it lead to legal issues ?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that someone will be offended, no matter what you do. From a legal perspective, India has [constitutionally protected freedom of expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_expression_in_India), but that doesn't mean you can say absolutely anything anywhere with no legal consequences (you can't threaten to kill a person). Restrictions are allowed under section 2 of [Article 19](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_India/Part_III#Article_19_.7BProtection_of_certain_rights_regarding_freedom_of_speech.2C_etc..7D) for reasons of "public order, decency or morality". There are, thus, [laws against "hate speech"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hate_speech_laws_in_India#Laws_restricting_the_freedom_of_expression) (which are unconstitutional in the US). Penal Code section153A says

> Whoever (a) by words, either spoken or written, or by signs or by
>   visible representations or otherwise, promotes or attempts to promote,
>   on grounds of religion, race, place of birth, residence, language,
>   caste or community or any other ground whatsoever, disharmony or
>   feelings of enmity, hatred or ill-will between different religious,
>   racial, language or regional groups or castes or communities, or (b)
>   commits any act which is prejudicial to the maintenance of harmony
>   between different religious, racial, language or regional groups or
>   castes or communities, and which disturbs or is likely to disturb the
>   public tranquillity, . . . shall be punished with imprisonment which
>   may extend to three years, or with fine, or with both.

Neutral quoting of Hitler is not *per se* forbidden hate speech, and unlike certain European countries, display of a *svastika* is not against the law -- probably not even the *Hakenkreuz*. What a court would look at is whether a given quote is "likely to disturb the public tranquillity".

Answer (score 1):

No. In India, for the vast majority of people, the symbolism does not have the charged meaning that it does in Europe or the United States.

On the other hand, Indians take a dim of foreigners in general, so if someone, especially a foreigner were to go waving around Nazi flags and preaching Nazism an arrest would be likely. This is true of any foreigner trying to propagandize. For example, foreign Christian missionaries are often arrested in India. The police in India have wide latitude in arresting people and imprisoning them.